# localStorage parsing issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a form with 4 input text boxes and on Save, I save the values to 4 localStorage variables.

Again on page load, I retrieve them and set 4 form labels with those values

```
$(".formFieldUserData").each(function(index)
            {
            var key = localStorage.key(index);
            $(this).val(localStorage.getItem($(this).attr('name')));
            $("#"+key+"Txt").html(localStorage.getItem($(this).attr('name')));
            });
```

Now there seems to be some order issue in Chrome. While Firefox sets the value perfectly, the localStorage seems to be accessed in a random order in Chrome.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Im not to sure on localstorage, but why not store an array in the local storage instead of individual names?

Comment: Can you show an example ?

Comment: I have 4 form fields with class formFieldUserData whose value I am trying to save...

Comment: Can you also show the localStorage dump from where you are trying to fetch the data? And you do know that localStorage is introduced in HTML5 and yet not completely compatible with some browsers. You might want to consider some library.

Comment: Yes, i know that browser support issue...but that is no problem...

Comment: My Local Storage looks like {desc: "d", email: "b", name: "a", phone: "c"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome stores the data sorted according to key(In your case it would be desc->email->name->phone). Other browsers have their own order. So you cant rely on the order for getting the data. You could use an array. But to my experience you can not store an associative arrays in localStorage (array with string keys). So if you want to store an associative array you will have to first `stringify` the array and store in localStorage and then to use it you can use `JSON.parse` and use it like object.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C4EuE/)